# Replace multiple strings between two indexes with in strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace, substring

I have a string. I want to replace `substrings` with in string. For each `substring` I have the starting and ending index. Using `regex` is out of scope.

So from let str = "I want chicken pizza and cheese pizza from point restaurant";

The expected result would be like this.

`I want TYPE1 TYPE4 and TYPE1 pizza from point restaurant`

```js
let str = "I want chicken pizza and cheese pizza from point restaurant";

let roles = [{
    "start": 7,
    "end": 14,
    "typeId": "TYPE1",
    "type": "toppings",
    "text": "chicken"
  },
  {
    "start": 25,
    "end": 31,
    "typeId": "TYPE1",
    "type": "toppings",
    "text": "cheese"
  },
  {
    "start": 15,
    "end": 20,
    "typeId": "TYPE4",
    "type": "main ingredient",
    "text": "pizza"
  }
];

let styledStr = str;
roles.map(r => {
  const { start, end, typeId, text } = r;
  let strArr = str.split('');
  let removeStr = strArr.splice(start, end, typeId);
  styledStr = strArr.join('');
  console.log(styledStr);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do not use a map if you do not need a
2. No need to split unless you MUST use splice

Method using start and end - **note** I sort the roles so we start at the highest position

```js
let str = "I want chicken pizza and cheese pizza from point restaurant";

let roles = [{
    "start": 7,
    "end": 14,
    "typeId": "TYPE1",
    "type": "toppings",
    "text": "chicken"
  },
  {
    "start": 25,
    "end": 31,
    "typeId": "TYPE1",
    "type": "toppings",
    "text": "cheese"
  },
  {
    "start": 15,
    "end": 20,
    "typeId": "TYPE4",
    "type": "main ingredient",
    "text": "pizza"
  }
];

let styledStr = str;
roles.sort((a,b)=>b.start-a.start)
roles.forEach(r => {
  const { start, end, typeId, text } = r;
  // Using substring because it is more readable and saves a split
  styledStr = styledStr.substring(0,start) + typeId + styledStr.substring(end)
  styledStr.slice(start,end,typeId)
});
console.log(styledStr)
```

Method using text replace

```js
let str = "I want chicken pizza and cheese pizza from point restaurant";

let roles = [{
    "start": 7,
    "end": 14,
    "typeId": "TYPE1",
    "type": "toppings",
    "text": "chicken"
  },
  {
    "start": 25,
    "end": 31,
    "typeId": "TYPE1",
    "type": "toppings",
    "text": "cheese"
  },
  {
    "start": 15,
    "end": 20,
    "typeId": "TYPE4",
    "type": "main ingredient",
    "text": "pizza"
  }
];

let styledStr = str;
roles.forEach(r => {
  const { start, end, typeId, text } = r;
  console.log(start,end,text)
  styledStr = styledStr.replace(text,typeId)
});
console.log(styledStr)
```

Comment: Excellent, I had tried the above but with sorting in descending order to persist the indexes, that line saved all the effort. Replace won't work in this case because if i want to change the second pizza not the first one, then it won't work.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

By replacing certain words, you are changing the length of the String, and thus your indices `start` and `end` won't hold the correct values anymore.

Also, you always start with `str.split()`, meaning you override a previous replacement saved in `styledStr`. This is the reason why only one replacement is visible at the end.

You should use `Array.forEach()` when performing actions based on the array's items, and use `Array.map()` to get a new array mapped from the old one.
`Array.forEach()` is what should be used here.

You can fix your code by starting the replacement from the back.

1. Sort `roles` in regards to either `start` or `end` in descending order
2. Replace in `styledStr`
3. Log to console

```js
let str = 'I want chicken pizza and cheese pizza from point restaurant';

let roles = [
  {
    start: 7,
    end: 14,
    typeId: 'TYPE1',
    type: 'toppings',
    text: 'chicken'
  },
  {
    start: 25,
    end: 31,
    typeId: 'TYPE1',
    type: 'toppings',
    text: 'cheese'
  },
  {
    start: 15,
    end: 20,
    typeId: 'TYPE4',
    type: 'main ingredient',
    text: 'pizza'
  }
];
    
let styledStr = str; // Start with raw string

// 1. Sort `roles` (will be in ascending order; reverse to get descending order)
roles.sort((o1, o2) => {
  if (o1.start < o2.start) return -1;
  if (o1.start == o2.start) return 0;
  return 1;
}).reverse();

// 2. Replace
roles.forEach(i => {
  let arr = styledStr.split(''); // Transform `styledStr` instead of `str`
  arr.splice(i.start, (i.end - i.start), i.typeId);
  styledStr = arr.join(''); // Save transformation in `styledStr`
});

// 3. Log to Console
console.log(styledStr);
```

Comment: Sorting using a function gives you the opportunity to sort in reverse order by reversing the values you return. No need to .reverse at all.

Answer (score -1):

```
enter code here
```

```js
let roles = [{
        "start" : 7,
        "end" : 14,
        "typeId" : "TYPE1",
        "type" : "toppings",
        "text" : "chicken"
    }, 
    {
        "start" : 25,
        "end" : 31,
        "typeId" : "TYPE1",
        "type" : "toppings",
        "text" : "cheese"
    }, 
    {
        "start" : 15,
        "end" : 20,
        "typeId" : "TYPE4",
        "type" : "main ingredient",
        "text" : "pizza"
    }
];

let str= `I want ${roles[0].typeId} ${roles[2].typeId} and ${roles[0].typeId}
 pizza from point restaurant`

console.log(str)
```

Comment: Actually in my case `roles` array is dynamic. The above solution won't be possible at my end.